# Magento 2: How to show the custom option in another phtml file

Tags: magento2, php, javascript

How can we override this position in custom option to show it in another phtml file.
[image]

added this code in `checkout_cart_index.xml` which override only the `form.phtml` not override the `default.phtml` file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<!-- <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/> -->
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
    </referenceBlock> 
     <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.override">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

i am getting error regarding the `checkout.cart.item.renderers` already has a child with alias 'simple' i have modify that file of `checkout_cart_item_renderer.xml`

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<!-- <update handle="checkout_item_price_renderers"/> -->
<body>
  <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
<action method="setOverriddenTemplates">
    <argument xsi:type="array">
        <!-- list override templates -->
        <item name="default" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
        <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
        <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">Bespoke_Bespoke::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
    </argument>
  </action>
  </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

to override the file we useed `etc/di.xml`

```
 <config  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\AbstractCart" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Checkout\Cart\AbstractCart"/><preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Option" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Product\View\Option"/>
   <preference for=" Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Checkout\Cart"/>
   <preference for="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" type="AGS\Bespoke\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer"/>
   <virtualType name="AGS\Bespoke\Model\ResourceModel\Bespoke\Bespoke\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">     
  <arguments><argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">ags_bespoke</argument><argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">AGS\Bespoke\Model\ResourceModel\Bespoke</argument> 

  </arguments></virtualType><type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
<arguments><argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
<item name="bespoke_record_bespoke_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">AGS\Bespoke\Model\ResourceModel\Bespoke\Bespoke\Collection</item>
```

Comment: remove the block in product detail page. add it in other page

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Because correct me if I'm wrong, but you need the options in order to be able to add the product to the cart in the first place. You cannot add a product with required options to the cart first, and select the options later.

Answer (score 5):

**Put the code in any other phtml page in product collection**

custome option willl show on dropdown , select , multiselect , etc...

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
<?php
    $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());
    $customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product); 
?>
  <?php 
    foreach($customOptions as $option){
      $values = $option->getValues();
      if (empty($values)) { 
          continue;
      } ?>
      <div class="custome-option">
          <?php foreach($values as $value) :  ?>
              <span><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></span>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
  <?php }; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: ,getting error : 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1):

**Show the custom option**

> Step-1 : Create registration.php file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog and add below code.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_Blog',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Step-2 : Create module.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog/etc and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_Blog" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

Step-3 : Create routes.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog/etc/frontend and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="blog" id="blog">
            <module name="VendoreName_Blog"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Step-4 : Create Index.php file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog/Controller/Index and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\Blog\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Custom Page'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> Step-5 : Create CustomBlock.php file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog/Block and add below code.

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\Blog\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CustomBlock extends Template
{
    protected $_productloader;
    protected $_imageBuilder;
    protected $_customOptions;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder $_imageBuilder,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $customOptions,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_imageBuilder = $_imageBuilder;
        $this->_customOptions = $customOptions;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoadProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
    }

    public function getImage($product, $attributes = [])
    {
        $imageId = 'product_base_image';
        return $this->_imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
            ->setImageId($imageId)
            ->setAttributes($attributes)
            ->create();
    }

    public function getCustomOptions($data)
    {
        return $this->_customOptions->getProductOptionCollection($data);
    }

    public function getOptionHtml($prd_data, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option)
    {
        $type = $this->getGroupOfOption($option->getType());
        $renderer = $this->getChildBlock($type);
        $renderer->setProduct($prd_data)->setOption($option);
        return $this->getChildHtml($type, false);
    }

    public function getGroupOfOption($type)
    {
        $group = $this->_customOptions->getGroupByType($type);
        return $group == '' ? 'default' : $group;
    }
}
```

> Step-6 : Create Customfile.phtml file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog/view/frontend/templates and add below code.

```
<?php
$id = 4;
// get product collection
$prd_data = $block->getLoadProduct($id);
// get product image
$image = $block->getImage($prd_data);
// get product option data
$prd_custom_op =  $block->getCustomOptions($prd_data);
?>
<div class="product-data-show-main">
    <div class="prd-name"><h2><?php echo $prd_data->getName(); ?></h2></div>
    <div class="product-image-part">
        <?= $image->toHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="product-options-part">
        <?php foreach ($prd_custom_op as $_option): ?>
            <?= $block->getOptionHtml($prd_data, $_option); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Step-7 : Create blog_index_index.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/Blog/view/frontend/layout and add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="VendoreName\Blog\Block\CustomBlock"
                   name="custom_option_show"
                   template="VendoreName_Blog::Customfile.phtml"
                   cacheable="false"
                   >
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType"
                       name="product.info.options.default"
                       as="default"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text"
                       name="product.info.options.text"
                       as="text"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File"
                       name="product.info.options.file"
                       as="file"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select"
                       name="product.info.options.select"
                       as="select"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date"
                       name="product.info.options.date"
                       as="date"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step-7 : Run Magento upgrade command after creating above file

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento c:f
```

> Step-8 : Run below URL

```
http://<yourhostname.com>/blog/index/index/
```

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Answer (score 0):

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Mode\Product')->load($_product->getId());
$customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Produc\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

foreach($customOptions as $option){
    $values = $option->getValues();
    if (empty($values)) { 
       continue;
    }?>
    <div class="custome-option">
    <?php
    foreach($values as $value){ ?>
        <span><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></span>
        <?php
    } ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
}
```

For more information visit below link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/324210/91098