# Magento 2 - How to get product custom option values in custom file?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, catalog, customizable-options

I want to override custom options template file.I want to show static image with each option value. I just create a custom file in Catalog module but don't know how to achieve this task?

> app/design/frontend/Occasionwear/m2-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom.phtml

[image]

Need help.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by values ? Can you describe more ?!

Comment: See screenshot. Need an image after each title.

Comment: First thing is your path is wrong, You are trying to override adminhtml part and you've created file at frontend. First Try to find in core code which file is responsible for your red marked section than copy that file to your theme at exact same location. Than Customize it.

Comment: These options are displaying on front end.I just add a screenshot to understand.

Comment: I ain't understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

using the below code you can get custom attribute value in phtml file.

```
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Mode\Product')->load($_product->getId());
    $customOptions = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Produc\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

    foreach($customOptions as $option){
        $values = $option->getValues();
        if (empty($values)) { 
           continue;
        }?>
        <div class="custome-option">
        <?php
        foreach($values as $value){ ?>
            <span><?php echo $value->getTitle(); ?></span>
            <?php
        } ?>
        </div>
        <?php 
    }
```